# Mysql: Select all rows of a linked table on parent's row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, call them `Parents` and `Properties`

Each parent has various columns and a `id` field. Each property has a `key`, a `value` column and a `parent_id` column that is a foreign key to the parent table. The key and the value can be any string. Each parent has zero or more properties.

How can I select *on the same row* the parent (and its columns) and all the linked properties? Thanks

**EDIT**
Its is **ok** for me to select all the joined values as a csv-like string, for example "key1|val1|key2|val2|key2|val2|".

**Example of wanted output**

```
|parent_id|parent_name|prop_key1|prop_val1|prop_key2|prop_val2|prop_key3|prop_val3|
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|1        |foo        |key1     |val1     |key2     |val2     |         |         |
|2        |foo        |key1     |val1     |key2     |val2     |key3     |val3     |
|3        |foo        |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|4        |foo        |key1     |val1     |key2     |val2     |key3     |val3     |
|4        |foo        |key1     |val1     |         |         |         |         |
```

**SAMPLE DATA**:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b770e

Comment: If you are going to ask a question like this, you should provide sample data, desired results, and a query that you have tried.  You have pretty good reputation on this site, so I'm surprised that you don't know how to write a good question.

Comment: Pivoting data can be implemented differently depending on the dbms. So which dbms are you using?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Please see the edit for sample of wanted output and sample schema / data

Comment: @vc74 MySql. In the edit the sample data

Comment: The perils of the EAV model.

Comment: Is there a limit how many properties a parent can have? Looking at the sample output, it seems like you expect up to 3...

Comment: @S.B. As stated in the question, Each parent has zero or more properties. For "or more" i mean infinite

Comment: @pistacchio well, then the answer would be to use GROUP_CONCAT, as outlined in the linked answer.